# How to resolve this problem with the code written in PHP for uploading files to a folder on my machine?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a problem with file uploading code in PHP. Have tried multiple variations of this code but none of those worked out particularly for me.
Note: I have tried with different browsers, folders, code editors(?). I have tried various tutorials but none of them seem to work for this.
If this is not a problem of the code what can I do to resolve this issue so that I can execute this on my machine(which is Windows 10)
Note: If I don't add isset($_FILES['file']) on the first line, error shows: "undefined index file" on subsequent lines.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['file']))
{
  $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $file_temporary_location = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $destination = "Files/";



//var_dump($_POST) and var_dump($_FILES)

C:\wamp64\www\sample.php:7:
array (size=1)
  'submit' => string 'Upload' (length=6)
C:\wamp64\www\sample.php:8:
array (size=1)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'download.png' (length=12)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php5176.tmp' (length=25)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 7471



  if(isset($file_name) && !empty($file_name))
  {
    move_uploaded_file($file_name,$destination); // or, move_uploaded_file($file_temporary_location,$destination.$file_name)
  }
}
?>

<form action="sample.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: First of all, go check what the configuration option `file_uploads` is set to. Second, do a var_dump of both $_POST and $_FILES, and show the results.

Comment: `// or, move_uploaded_file($file_temporary_location,$destination.$file_name)` Have you tried using this, which looks like the correct way to move temporary files?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for responding. I have  checked .ini file and the file_uploads option is set to 'on'. I have also updated the second part of your suggestion in my code. Please check.

Comment: @kerbh0lz Thanks for your response. YES, I have tried that one variation too. But it didn't work as expected.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` will raise a warning, if the file is a valid upload file, but can’t be moved for some reason. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go do so now, and see what you get.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your response. I tried this and my problem was solved : move_uploaded_file($file_temporary_location , "upload/" . $filename);

Comment: Knowing your folder names helps a lot

Comment: @kerbh0lz Thanks for responding. By the way problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
move_uploaded_file($file_temporary_location , "upload/" . $filename);
```

the code above mean that php told browser to take the file which has been uploaded via input type file  and put it in files folder (in your case must be in the same dir )

the file_name is stored in your hard drive the file_temporary_location stored in your browser cashed

I hope this help you  ^_^